# Execute fstrim weekly with a user-set crontab

Tags: system-installation, scripts, cron, logging

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.04.  My Linux experience is limited.

I would like to execute `fstrim` weekly.  Ubuntu already has a script set up in `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`, but it does not do exactly what I want it to.  I would like to save the output of this to a cumulative log and I am wondering: what is the best way to achieve this.

At the same time, I wish to facilitate my installs so I have personal requirements:

- From a fresh OS install, `sudo crontab -e` is the only acceptable change outside of `/home` for the solution to work (i.e. no need to modify default file `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`)
- Log files must be stored to my preferred format, in a dedicated file in `/home/user/path/to/mylogfile.txt`

So I now understand that it is safe to `sudo vi /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` as it is a script file rather and than a crontab (in other words: a command similar to `crontab -e` is not required for OS-native weekly jobs stored there), but...

Question #2 - The end goal is `calling fstrim weekly` while ensuring it is performed only once per week on the system.  Are there any errors or problems with the following solution?:

Set up root's crontab such that:

```
$ sudo crontab -l
@weekly /home/user/path/to/myscript.sh
```

Have an executable file `/home/user/path/to/myscript.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim ]; then
    mv /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim /home/user/cron_backups/fstrim.orig
fi

# trim all mounted file systems which support it, and log results
/sbin/fstrim -v --all || true >> /home/user/path/to/mylogfile.txt
```

[END]

Comment: @A.B. isn't that a case of _partial_ duplication ?  -- Q1: Yes, you can `sudo vi` into `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`. Whether it is safe depends on what you do next.  No need to reboot, I believe. In doing so you will edit a SCRIPT, whereas `crontab -e` edits the crontab itself, i.e. the scheduling of your cron jobs.  -- Q2: i) backup yr `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` before using `\rm -f`on it. ii) Note that only root has write permission; you need root privilege to remove it. How you do it w/o entering yr sudo passwd, i.e. in the context of a cron job, is documented online.

Comment: Thank you for your explaining the differences, I missed the script/crontab differentiation.  Thank you also for your comment about privileges, I will make some edits.

Comment: Pbms: you do not have write permission on `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`so you can't `chmod` w/ normal user's privileges. Use `sudo chmod` or be root. `cron` may complain it cannot execute that non-executable job.  If it does, move script _outside_  cron.weekly. Same privilege comments apply to `mv`. Can you explain why you would want to do what you propose. I am sure I'm not the only one to be puzzled. Last but not least make sure you understand rwx privileges and do a `\ls -l /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` so you know what you are dealing with privilege wise.  HTH. (Reply to me with @Cbhihe if need be)

Comment: `fstrim` runs daily on my machine. Don't you have a file named `/etc/cron.daily/trim`?

Comment: @Cbhihe Since the check/move was in root's crontab, I thought privileges were ok.  I also thought `fstrim` needed root privileges to execute (I may be wrong) so it was in root's crontab I was thinking of calling my own script.  The purpose of what I was hoping to do, in a few words, is to install new systems in a minimum amount of time - using a somewhat generic /home partition and 1 edit of root's crontab.  Moving `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` to `/some/backup/folder` may be more elegant, I have to agree.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini No, I do not have `trim` in a daily script; only `fstrim` in weekly (fresh install).  From `man fstrim`:  Running  fstrim frequently, or even using mount -o discard, might negatively affect the lifetime of poor-quality SSD devices.  For most desktop and server systems the sufficient trimming frequency is once a week.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: invoking `fstrim` on a daily basis is good, e.g. for data intensive high write and throughput database servers. It is unlikely tobe many people's case.  If you do this on any John Doe's regular Samsung SSD (such as in my case), you will shorten the SSD's lifespan for no valid reason. SSDs just like a human heart only last so long. Their lifetime does not  amount to so many beats, but to so many write operations.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that my `/etc/cron.daily/trim` has been automatically installed, not by me, but by a package

Comment: The package `util-linux` should install `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`. It's not the same as my script (not sure where I got mine from, probably from a dev version of Ubuntu) but still you should have it too, as util-linux is an essential package.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini; I have no clue about what could put a file system trimming script in yr /etc/cron.daily/ .. I have quite a few security-related optional things on my own in there, but certainly not fstrim.  On a daily basis, it would be too much of a good thing for my systems. Worth a look in the direction of databases and DB management packages maybe ?